How to show the number of data points that fall into each bin in pyplot
I have this list of ages of respondents and I'm plotting a histogram using matplotlib.pyplot and everything is fine except for the fact that I can't see the exact number of respondents over each bar. Is there a way to do that? I see the scales along the axis but I want to see the exact number over each bar (in each bin). Is there a way to do that, like a special parameter or something?

A histogram or a bar graph? This sounds like Axes.bar_label.

@BigBen a histogram. I'm new to the topic, sorry if I used the term interchangeably and incorrectly
